# How to run a Django post_save signal as a background process?

Tags: django, asynchronous, heroku

I have a [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save) attached to a model which loads a substantial amount of information via json response from an external API when it is created. Unfortunately this takes long enough that heroku times out before it ever has a chance of finishing.

After doing some research is seems the best way to do this is as a background process.

**What would be the best way to run a post_save signal asynchronously?**

After reading about celery it seems too heavy-weight for one process. Are there other methods that are trusted?

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
import urllib2
import json

class Foobar(models.Model):
    # ... fields ... #

def foobar_post_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    """Load info from external API

    data
    ----
    sender - The model class. (Foobar)
    instance - The actual instance being saved.
    created - Boolean; True if a new record was created.
    *args, **kwargs - Capture the unneeded `raw` and `using`(1.3) arguments.
    """

    if created:
        url_to_open = <api_url>
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(url_to_open)
        data = json.loads(resp.read())
        # ... load data ... #

post_save.connect(foobar_post_save, sender=Foobar)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer with [rq](http://python-rq.org) which has a nice [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq)

And implemented like so:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
import urllib2
import json
from rq import Queue
from worker import conn

q = Queue(connection=conn)

class Foobar(models.Model):
    # ... fields ... #

    def load_data(self):
        url_to_open = <api_url>
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(url_to_open)
        data = json.loads(resp.read())
        # ... load data ... #

def foobar_post_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    """Load info from external API

    data
    ----
    sender - The model class. (Foobar)
    instance - The actual instance being saved.
    created - Boolean; True if a new record was created.
    *args, **kwargs - Capture the unneeded `raw` and `using`(1.3) arguments.
    """

    if created:
        q.enqueue(instance.load_data, timeout=600)

post_save.connect(foobar_post_save, sender=Foobar)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure that this is exactly what you want, but I've done a similar thing, so I think this will do what you need.

```
import multiprocessing

proc = multiprocessing.Process(
    target = foobar_post_save,           #the function to be run
    args = (sender,instance,created),    #the arguments to pass to the function
    name="foobar post save")             #name not strictly necessary
proc.start()     #starts the process
proc.join(60)    #wait until this is done; optional time limit is in seconds
```

For more on this, see here: [Python 3 multiprocessing module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: I'm not sure this can work in this situation. Because django handles the calling of post_save signals somewhere in `models.Model.save()` I think I would have to overload that method to call `.start()` on the process. I was hoping there would be something less ugly

Comment: Well, I don't use Heroku, and that similar thing I did didn't involve the post_save signal, so I don't think I can help you much further. Sorry.

Comment: +1 I had to reorganize my code a little but It looks like this method would work. However rq fits my needs a little better so I'm going to mark that as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given you need an asynchronous approach, what about using [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), to run your long running task and then trigger that from your app's `post_save`.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with celery, but as I mentioned in the question it seems pretty heavy-weight just for executing one process, I was wondering it there was anything simpler?

Comment: I guess the issue is that long-running processes should ideally be kept out of the request-response cycle to improve experience for the user, and stop your server process being held up by the slow task. The fact you're hitting the timeout suggests that it is a bit too lengthy to be considered reasonable for a request-response. There may be other simpler queues out there, but I'd go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea using [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/) or something similar to start a task in the background. So, you create a new task on Celery after **post_save** and then you can monitor that task to stop / pause / get success signal / etc.