# Scheduled task with Django

Tags: django, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on a web app which manages events. I store data about them such as their starting time. I would like to execute a task (in this case, sending a mail to the event administrator). There shouldn't be there more than 10 events a day and the sending would just involve one mail. I've been reading about different approaches such as a writing custom command amd executing it with cron, but as long as the sending time depends on each event, I think it wouldn't be a nice solution.
I have read as well about Celery, but in this case I think that would be a too powerful and heavy tool for my needs. Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

There are other alternatives. [RQ (Redis Queue)](http://python-rq.org/) is one of them. It is a simple Python library for queueing jobs and processing them in the background with workers. You can use `post_save` [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) and RQ together, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33902618/1257959).